# Google Calender API only fetching first event of calendar

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to make a simple python desktop app that displays my tasks for the day. For that i'm using the Google Calendar API to fetch the events of my personal calendar. I should also mention that am a beginner in python programming and have no experience with the API itself, which is probably why i have ran into this problem.
I used the quickstart code from the google developers page for the API. But for some reason it only returns the summary of the first event on the calender when it's supposed to display the first 10. I have a separate file to display the data returned from the quickstart, but the problem shouldn't lie there as a print statement in the quickstart also only prints a single event.

Here is the code i only slightly modified from the quickstart.py from Google:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import datetime
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials


SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly']


def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Google Calendar API.
    Prints the start and name of the next 10 events on the user's calendar.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds)


    # Call the Calendar API
    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z'  # 'Z' indicates UTC time
    events_result = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', timeMin=now,
                                          maxResults=10, singleEvents=True,
                                          orderBy='startTime').execute()
    events = events_result.get('items', [])


    if not events:
        print('No upcoming events found.')
    for event in events:
        time = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
        title = event['summary']
        # print(event['summary'], time)
        return title, time


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The google developers API reference isn't much help to me either, so does anyone know what causes this problem?

Also, how do i get the data from all the calendars, instead of just the primary one?

Answer (score 2):

Execute returns results by pages (size constrained by `maxResults`) - and the reason you see only the first event is probably due to 2 issues:

1. You are looking only at the first page of results
2. Passing `singleEvents=True` returns only the first instance of recurring events. This means that if your calendar has any recurring event (daily/ weekly etc.) you will get only the first occurrence of the event in the results. If you want to get all the events (and as I understand that's what you want) - you need to remove this parameter.
   Try incorporating the following code instead to solve your problem:

   ```
    result = []
    page_token = None

    while True:
        page = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', 
                                     timeMin=now,
                                     maxResults=10,
                                     orderBy='startTime',
                                     pageToken=page_token).execute()
        result.extend(page["item"])
        page_token = page.get('nextPageToken')

        if not page_token:
            break

    return result
   ```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion! I incorporated your snippet yet now i get an error message saying i'm missing a valid API key. I don't understand why i'm getting this message, as i have been able to fetch google calendar data before.

Comment: Maybe your API key expired? Did you create a temporary token? What line causes the error? Can you paste the error here

Comment: I don't think the API key expired, as it seems to work again when i comment in my old code. The console gives me the error at the line were page = service.events().list(...) is made. The error itself provides a link that that displays the following text: ` {
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
} `

Comment: The formatting is most likely messed up but it boils down to the message of not having a valid API key. Furthermore, the error in the console also says: `"The requested ordering is not available for the particular query.". Details: "The requested ordering is not available for the particular query.">`

Comment: Let's try to solve it one at a time.
Regarding the permissions can you explain exactly what code did you substitute with my code. Basically it should be everything below the "# Call the Calendar API" comment.
Regarding the second error - it might be a side effect of the permissions issue or there might be conflicting parameters in the list request

Comment: Yes, i replaced the code like you described, with exception of the now = datetime... variable as it is needed as a parameter in the list() function. Regarding the errors, the first and second error are actually one and the same error, bad copy pastingon my part. The whole error message is like this:

Comment: googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?timeMin=2021-04-13T12%3A32%3A59.718925Z&maxResults=10&orderBy=startTime&alt=json returned "The requested ordering is not available for the particular query.". Details: "The requested ordering is not available for the particular query.">

Comment: Can you try to remove the order by parameter and see if it works?

Comment: Doing that gives me the following error: C:/.../quickstart.py", line 52, in main
    result.extend(page["item"])
KeyError: 'item'

Comment: So I think that parameter is required